# Can I force OneNote to ONLY look for LOCAL notebooks when it starts?

Tags: microsoft-onenote-2013

When I reboot my **Win8.1** laptop, **login** with a **local account** and try to **open OneNote**, I'm asked to provide MS Account credentials. For security reasons, **I do not want any data stored on OneDrive**: I need my notebooks local to my laptop.
Having created my notebooks locally, I do not even need (nor want I) to provide MS Account credentials.

I only managed to do it when I unlinked my local account from my MS Account. Ever since the very first reboot, **I am unable to start OneNote without being asked for my MS Account credentials**. Basically I cannot access the information I entered during the very first session: very, very annopying!